# Git SSH key-pair stopped working after a location change

Tags: ssh, git

I have used the same public key scheme to ssh to my server that hosts its own git repository. Recently, I changed the location from where I work from (different IP), and now git asks for my password every time I log in.

I'm using Windows to connect to my server, pageant to keep track of the authentication.

I've looked in the auth log files on my server, and each login shows that the public key WAS indeed accepted, yet I am still getting prompted for the pswd on every action.

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed this by just reinstalling git / tortoise, this time using OpenSSH instead of plink.
http://ys.lancop.nl/site/?p=62 helped a lot

Answer (score 2):

Private key access can be restricted by host.  Verify that the public key stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys doesn't have a qualifier restricting which hosts it is valid for.