# Setting up Git over SSH on Windows using a non-standard port

Tags: windows, ssh, git, putty

I had to switch from Ubuntu so that I could use Adobe Suite at full speed and now I'm finding that SSH on windows is not as unified as on linux.

So I installed [msysgit](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) and [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) but I'm finding that git is having trouble using putty for SSH. (I did install msysgit on the windows path and using plink).

I am trying to add a remote on my git project now to a server on a non-standard port by using a /.ssh/config file like

```
Host 255.255.255.255
Port 22222
```

Then I add the data to my git repo:

```
git remote add origin user@255.255.255.255:~/git/repo
```

But when I try to push I get an error message.

```
$ git push origin master
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

---

So then I tried just using SSH from the git console:

```
ssh user@255.255.255.255
```

Which prompts me for my private key passphrase (which it doesn't have) and when I fail at that it asks me for my SSH user password (which works).

Since I am going to disable SSH login by password I need git to start using my key correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar workflow but use gitosis to manage the repo on my VPS.

I use the msysgit bash with the windows path and plink as you suggest above but in addition I use [pagent](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to manage the SSH key.

To access my repos this is the order I take,

- Open Pagent and access my key (you only enter the passphrase here once if you have one and even if you do it remembers it for the whole session).
- Then open Git bash and add/commit/push/pull/clone as normal.

One caveat I will note is that I had to convert the key I created with the Git bash using Putty Gen (available on the same link above) so that Pagent could use it.

Comment: Don't forget to `set GIT_SSH=C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe`

Comment: Not having pagent running was half my problem - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't specifying the connection string correctly.

```
$ git remote add test ssh://user@domain.tld:22222/~/git/repo
```

I also didn't have pagent running to manage my keys for me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept not having a passphrase on that key, you could removing the passphrase... otherwise [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/153023/git-ssh-key-pair-stopped-working-after-a-location-change) might provide some guidance.

Comment: Thats just it, my private key doesn't have a passphrase yet it's still asking for one.